# Type 'By' has no properties in common with type 'Locator'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have issue when i try rebuild my project , i get following error:

```
Type 'By' has no properties in common with type 'Locator'
```

[image]

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It sounds like there is a conflict with the name `by` where the compiler or test runner doesn't actually know that it is referring to the wrong `by`.  You might try importing `by as by2` and then try `element(by2.css(...))` to see if that resolves it.  If it does, this confirms that it is probably a name conflict.  I would NOT recommend continuing with that (by2) as a workaround though.  The issue might be in the environment you're coding in.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in Protractor 4.x / Webdriver. the `element` method expects a `Locator` but `by.css` returns a `webdriver.by` object. To fix this compilation error you need to cast it to a `Locator` like:

```
import { Locator } from 'protractor/built/locators';
...
element(<Locator>by.css('h1'))
```